# How to retrieve duplicate nodes from XML using xpath or java script

Tags: java, xml, xslt, groovy, duplicates

Below is my input xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Hierarchy>

<Records>

<Org_Unit_Name>ABC</Org_Unit_Name>

<Parent_Org_Unit>123</Parent_Org_Unit>

</Records>

<Records>

<Org_Unit_Name>ABC</Org_Unit_Name>

<Parent_Org_Unit>DEF</Parent_Org_Unit>

</Records>

<Records>

<Org_Unit_Name>456</Org_Unit_Name>

<Parent_Org_Unit>879</Parent_Org_Unit>

</Records>

</Hierarchy>
```

I would like to extract only duplicate values. so the output should be as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Hierarchy>

<Records>

<Org_Unit_Name>ABC</Org_Unit_Name>

<Parent_Org_Unit>123</Parent_Org_Unit>

</Records>

<Records>

<Org_Unit_Name>ABC</Org_Unit_Name>

<Parent_Org_Unit>DEF</Parent_Org_Unit>

</Records>
```

I tried preceding axes in xpath/xslt, but of no use and unique(false) in java script but I am unable to retrieve the expected output. Please guide me how to proceed forward.

Regards,

Amuktha

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed.

Comment: You need to specify **exactly** what constitutes a "duplicate". The given example can be interpreted in more than one way.

Comment: You tagged [java] and [groovy], but your subject claims "xpath" or "java script"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "duplicate" means a `Records` element with the  same `Org_Unit_Name` value, you could use a variation of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="Records-by-Org_Unit_Name" match="Records" use="Org_Unit_Name" />

<xsl:template match="/Hierarchy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Records[count(key('Records-by-Org_Unit_Name', Org_Unit_Name)) > 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```